# key-value-pair how to access values from within list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a key value pair information table of field-name and value I was going use linq to get the all the values back but my question is:

What is the best way to process this? ie I need to be able to access the values within this list and assign them to the textboxes. I am using it on a form that has hundreds of fields which I want to set the value to once I retrieve it from the below method

```
public List<tblPortalIandEValue> GetValuesByUserId(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        List<tblPortalIandEValue> _iandeValues = new List<tblPortalIandEValue>();

        _iandeValues = (from _iande in portalEntities.tblPortalIandEValues
                        where _iande.userId == id && _iande.isDeleted == false && _iande.isActive==true
                        select _iande)
                       .ToList();

        return _iandeValues;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string inner = string.Empty;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        
        // logger.Error("Error in GetValuesByUserId function aperturenetdal " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
        return null;
    }
}
```

At present I was doing this which I think it's very inefficient

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userId"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public decimal getiandEData(Guid _userId ,string Keyname)
{
    try
    {
        var _iandeValue = portalEntities.tblPortalIandEValues
                                        .Where(f => f.isDeleted == false && f.userId == _userId && f.field_name == Keyname)
                                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.field_name)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
        return Convert.ToDecimal(_iandeValue.field_value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string inner = string.Empty;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        // logger.Error("Error in IQueryable function getAllApointments " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
        
        return Convert.ToDecimal("0.00");
    }
}
```

And Finally filling the value is there a better way of assigning the data ?

```
clientearningscic.Value = Decimal.Round(_dal.getiandEData(_myuser.id, "clientearningscic"),2) ;
```

The table will basically contain:

> id fieldname fieldvalue
>
> 1  gas       25.00
>
> 2  electric  30.50

Comment: What is this linq to objects?

Comment: it is linqI am asking for suggestions on implmenetation

Comment: If the table isn't too large, I would load all (necessary) data into a global dictionary of fieldname and fieldvale. Then retrieve the necessary information from that object. This way you would prevent DB call every single time you need the info.